# How to set an user as admin [rails]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

i'm trying to set an user as admin and this is the code I wrote so far:

**app/controllers/users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  before_action :admin_user,     only: [:destroy]
  ..
  ..
  def admin_user
    redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user && current_user.admin?
  end

end
```

**db/seeds.rb**

```
User.create!(name:  "admin",
             surname: "admin",
             email: "admin@1.it",
             password:              "password",
             password_confirmation: "password",
             admin: true)
```

So, when I create an user with these specs it doesn't work as well: typing 'localhost:3000/users,it redirects me to root_url instead of users page..
Can someone help me? what's wrong with this code?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you show the log of this action ?

Comment: Is  `user.admin?` is a method on your model? If not, then I believe it should say `current_user.admin` instead of `current_user.admin?`

Comment: Your `before_action` only runs before the destroy action, so it will not affect you visiting http://localhost:3000/users .

Comment: You also haven't said anything about being logged in when you access this URL.

Comment: in the definition of the admin_user method I write that, if the logged user is not the admin, localhost:3000/users will automatically link me to root..in my humble opinion the issued should be in the seeds file, because the prog can't see that user as admin, am I wrong?

Comment: @Pino Since sevenseacat answered you alread, the problem in the code of controller that you haven't shown for us.

Comment: Just an additional comment to the above. I don't see any need in making a **seed** with an admin user. Wouldn't it be much easier to just `User.first.toggle!(:admin)` inside the console?

Answer (score 1):

OK here is how i set up my admin:

1. do a migration to add a admin boolean column to users. it should look something like this

> ```
> class AddAdminToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
>   def change
>     add_column :users, :admin, :boolean, default: false
>   end
> end
> ```

2. In the controller of the elements that you want admin restriction write a method that looks something like this

> ```
> def require_admin
>      if !current_user.admin?
>            redirect_to benefits_path
>      end
> end
> ```

3. On the top of that controller write the before_action stuff
4. user the rails console to toggle one of the users from admin false to admin true
5. test your admin rights

Answer (score 0):

Kindly go through [Rolify](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify) gem.

With this gem you can define different roles for different users and validating users for there roles is also very easy.

Answer (score 0):

Ok kindly use before_filter if using rails3.

```
before_filter :admin_user,     only: [:index]
```